# Why didn't John the Baptist become Christ's Disciple

Tags: jesus, john-the-baptist, messiah

While we see clearly that John The Baptist pointed people to Christ and testified that Christ is the Messiah (John 3:28,30, Luke 3:15-18) why is it that he himself didn't follow Christ. John still had his own disciples (Matthew 11:2) despite the fact that the one (Jesus) who he was testifying to was there in person. Also, John was seemingly meddling in politics of the day by pointing out the sins of the Herod (Luke 3:19-20). There does not appear to be a situation where Jesus pointed out the sins of secular leaders at His time. Do you believe that if John had followed Jesus completely (Matthew 16:24-25, John 3:25-30) and told his remaining disciples (Matthew 11:2) to follow Jesus as well, he wouldn't have had his moment of doubt by sending them to ask if Jesus was the Messiah (Matthew 11:3)?

Comment: The question has been edited to include references to the scriptures.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to BH. I have edited my questions, please let me know if this current version is better.

Comment: John was a Baptist, and baptists obviously need water to baptize. In the hot and dry climate of the Holy Land, the Jordan was a very large and important river. Not quite sure what else there is to say.